# Stuck in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: upgrade, 10.10

I Opened my old laptop for the first time in years , and it's still on Ubuntu 10.10. Can't seem to figure out how to get it to upgrade to the most recent version.

Any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't really do an upgrade from 10.10 to a recent version without passing through a lot of intermediate versions. A better plan would be to do a clean install after copying any files you want to keep elsewhere.

Also, if it's that old, you might consider [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), as it is less demanding of memory and processing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, 10.10 is an unsupported and obsolete version as per [Upgrade Notes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29/)

However; you may have a look to the following [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/) for some work around.

another suggestion -although lengthy and requires a lot of downloads is to download 11.04 and 11.10 ISOs from [Ubuntu Old Releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) and do an offline upgrade 10.10 > 11.04 > 11.10

- Nice guide with illustrations [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu/)

then you should be able to upgrade normally from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS

and for sure, **Lubuntu** is the best candidate for your old laptop.